# If $f$ is a holomorphic function on $D(z_0, R)$ where $f(z_0) = 0$, then there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(z_0) \neq 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, power-series

I want to show that

> If $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, $R > 0$ and $f$ is analytic on the disk $D(z_0, R)$ where $f(z_0) = 0$, then there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(z_0) \neq 0$.

Below is the start of my proof, and would like some tips on how to finish this proof.

Since $f$ is an analytic function on $D$, then $f$ can be expressed a power series of the form
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_k(z - z_0)^k, k = 0, 1, 2,...
\end{equation*}
where $a_k = \dfrac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}$. Then since $f(z_0) = 0$ is a zero of order $n$, this implies that
\begin{equation*}
a_0 = 0, a_1 = 0, a_2 = 0,...,a_{n - 1} = 0 \ \text{but} \ a_n \neq 0
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = (z - z_0)^n \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{n + k}(z - z_0)^k
\end{equation*}

I am not sure how to proceed from here and would like some assistance. Thanks.

Comment: You must assume that $f$ is not identically zero, otherwise the statement is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR I forgot to include $\setminus \{z_0\}$ for $\Phi(z)$, thank you.

Comment: $a_n \ne 0$ implies $f^{(n)}(z_0) = n! a_n \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are assuming $f$ is not the constant zero function.

By contradiction works better. Suppose it is the case that $a_k=0$ for all $k$. Then $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 0\cdot (z-z_0)^k = 0$ for all $z$. But we assumed $f$ is not the constant zero function; hence there must exist a $k$ such that $a_k\not=0$.